# MotionLayout - Single continuous transition on swipe?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

I have four different layouts which can be swiped one after another by swiping left.

When a single transition completes, I would like to be able to continue on to another transition upon further swiping left. All layouts have their own transitions when swiping down. What I have currently is a lot of transitions and am setting `transitionToState()` each time a button is pressed.

Is there a way to achieve this as of now in MotionLayout with just a swipe action? `A way to chain transitions into one single transition by swiping left each time.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is yes if it is not associated with a nestedScrollView (like recycler view).

In general if you have 3 states A,B & C and two Transitions A->B & B->C with OnSwipe in the same direction in both. They will naturally "chain"
I.E.
Width touch down in state A it will drag A to B then B to C.
Touch up before B and it will stop at B.
There is no simple way to prevent B being a valid stop.

More details on onSwipe in this [video](https://youtu.be/XtnAZXM26wQ?t=142)

For example this layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/motionLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#FF003b60"
  app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene"
  app:motionDebug="SHOW_PATH">
<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#5F3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Using MotionScene file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <Transition
    motion:constraintSetStart="@id/a"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/b">
    <OnSwipe motion:dragDirection="dragRight" />
  </Transition>

  <Transition
    motion:constraintSetStart="@id/b"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/c">
    <OnSwipe motion:dragDirection="dragRight" />
  </Transition>

  <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/a">
    <ConstraintOverride android:id="@+id/view"
        motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0" />
  </ConstraintSet>

  <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/b"/>

  <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/c">
    <ConstraintOverride android:id="@id/view"
        motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1" />
  </ConstraintSet>
  </MotionScene>
```

This Motion scene has 3 ConstraintSets a,b, & c It also has two transitions a->b and b->c both have on swipes